# Best Practice for Laravel Validation

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5.8, laravel-6.2

I Create New form request and use this for all CRUD operations

and use `$this->getMethod();` to check the different between requests

then I face logical issues

1. Is all fields that **required** in store method should be **required** in update method ?

   => the question here is should the consumer of APIs should sent all keys object to update specific key
2. If It shouldn't and the keys name sent from APIs is different from the Database table columns name

   => I can't use `update($request()->all());` because the key isn't the same as columns name, then I need to **loop** on all request keys to ignore the key that have null - can be done also by **multi-check** -

So please what the best practice of that ??

Comment: You can use `$request->validated()` which will only return the values from the request that have actually been validated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways of validating data in Laravel.

What I prefer is not to write validation checks in a controller and write it in a separate form request and use that request object as a parameter.

Let's assume we are having a user model and a name is required and a unique in `store` and `update` methods of your controller, you can simply use `UserRequest` object as described below.

##### Create a form request class

```sh
php artisan make:request UserRequest
```

```
class UserRequeset extends Request
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $id = request('id') ?: 'NULL'; // To identify if a request is for store or update just take autoincremented id parameter from request

         return [
             'name' => "required|unique:users,name,$id"
         ];


        // You can also customize your validation for different methods as below

        switch ($this->method()) {
            case 'POST':
                return [
                    // validation for post method
                ];
            break;
            case 'PUT':
                return [
                    // validation for put method
                ];
            break;
            default:
                return [];
            break;
        }

    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            "name.required" => "User name is required",
            "name.unique" => "User name should be unique"

            // or you can customize this using language

            "name.required" => __("user.required_message"),
            "name.unique" => __("user.unique_message")
        ];
    }
}
```

##### in `UserController`

```
use App\Http\Requests\UserRequest;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function store(UserRequest $request)
    {
        // Enter your code just after validation part no need of any validation code here
    }
    public function update(UserRequest $request)
    {
        // Enter your update code just after validation part no need of any validation code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok the question here if I have name and phone and both is not allow null in database, 
if the section of PUT, POST
in POST (insertion) all is required, and in update user may change name or phone or both so 
if I should enter required in both POST and PUT for the 2 fields ??

Comment: even user want to update one of them, or user should sent the full object if it updated or not

Comment: probably yes, `required` should be in both the methods

Comment: also instead of using method checking you can simply follow the first step which will work same for both the cases.

Comment: I guess the validation should gose to Model. Not in The HTTP request. Since laravel is MVC framework.

Comment: Model is where you can define attributes, Cast the types, relationships, etc and validation is required only for the request so Laravel has provided request validation. @LeoS

Comment: Ok. I understand. I am convinced. But, I feel like still this is strange logic to me. So, everyone make a validation like that? Additonal source code also make application slows down I guess.

Comment: @LeoS yes laravel provides two ways to validate, either we can validate request in the controller or we can make request separately, and for your second thought, it won't make your application slow.

Comment: @PrateikDarji Well... in my opinion, if we put the validation in the main Controller, the controller would be very long program in some cases. So, I often put my validation in Model and make the controller clean and shotter. So, this case I better put my validation in the HTTP request.

Comment: @LeoS that's true and I totally agree with you as well, as there are different thoughts the answer can not be the same for everyone, here I just provide steps for best practice in laravel.

Comment: For anyone looking a this answer, personal recommendation, always create a different `FormRequest` for each action (`store`, `update`, whenever you need it), because you are going to end up with that super ugly check...

Comment: @matiaslauriti thanks for the recommendation, for the code where the logic and validations are different while storing and updating the data then yes, I agree with you one should use different FormRequest for specific methods.

Comment: @PrateikDarji You should have different checks for `store` and `update`, because in one you may check you have required fields, but on the `update`, you may only get the updated field instead of everything. So, it makes sense to always have different files. But it is a personal based recommendation

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the following approach:

```
$this->validate(
    $request,
    [
        'YOUR INPUT FIELD NAME' => 'required',
    ]
);
```

---

You can also use `$request->validate()` since Laravel 5.5+:

```
$request->validate(
    [
        'YOUR INPUT FIELD NAME' => 'required',
    ]
);
```

Comment: In both update and store method ??

Comment: Yes, It has always worked out for me. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'phone' => 'sometimes|max:255',
    'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
    'pic_file' => 'sometimes|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif|max:1000',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect('/')->withErrors($validator);
}
```

Comment: You are literally recreating a [`FormRequest`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#form-request-validation), don't do that and literally use a `FormRequest`...